# Google Calendar automatic count down

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to use Google Calendar so that a counter is added to each entry.

For example, an annual leave calendar where I have a set amount to start with 20 (which is displayed in the Google Calendar entry) and every day I add to the calendar the number gets decremented automatically, thus telling me how much I have left?